# Onclick change backgroundcolor and after other function run

Tags: javascript, function, background, onclick

I wanna onclick which my quiz correct question
.change background color and 1 or 2 second after myDiv display none
this correct...but i wanna first mydiv change background color then read this function...

```
    function duzgun() {
if (ikiSual.style.display = "none") {
    ikiSual.style.display = "block"
    ucSual.style.display = "none"
    dordSual.style.display = "none"
    besSual.style.display = "none"
    birSual.style.display = "none"
    }
} else {
    alert("sehv cavabdi")

}
```

}

Comment: your question is not clear. please write more details and code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it:

```js
function setbackground() {
    document.getElementById("element").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    setTimeout(duzgun, 3000);//3000 = 3 seconds, 2000 = 2 seconds
}
function duzgun() {
    if (ikiSual.style.display = "none") {
        ikiSual.style.display = "block"
        ucSual.style.display = "none"
        dordSual.style.display = "none"
        besSual.style.display = "none"
        birSual.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        alert("sehv cavabdi")
    }
}
```